# How can I write an Applescript to resize an application window on external monitor

Tags: resize, window, applescript, macos-mojave

I want to write an Applescript to resize the Safari window on my external screen.
I have a Macbook Air Screen of 1440x900 and an Asus external monitor of 2560x1440.
I want to keep Safari on my external monitor, with a 170 pixel gap on the left-hand side.
I wrote the following basic script:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        set bounds of window 1 to {170, 0, 2560, 1440}
    end tell
end tell
```

The result is that the only Safari window open gets moved from my external monitor to my Macbook Air (Mojave) screen with the correct width (2560-170 = 2390) and incorrect height (900 and not the 1440 specified).

How do I ensure the correct width and height AND keep the window on my external monitor.
Many thanks.

Comment: It also depends on how your screens are arranged. For example, I have my external on top of my laptop, in the same x-coordinates, so for me to position anything on my external monitor, my y position would be the negative height of my external screen.

Comment: Excellent. I wasn't thinking of the screen real estate being accessible with negative coordinates. Thanks, that really helps.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is manually place the **Safari** _window_ exactly where you want it and the size you want it, then run `tell application "Safari" to return bounds of window 1`, now you have the coordinates. To repeatedly set the window where you want it and the size you want it take the `bounds` returned from the first _command_ and change the _command_  to set the `bounds`, e.g.:  `tell application "Safari" to set the bounds of window 1 to {n, n, n, n,}`

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you don't need to use System Events; Safari knows how to resize its own windows. All you need to do is  get the bounds of the window, change the last two items of the returned list, and then set the bounds to the revised array. This will change the size without moving the position of the window.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set old_bounds to bounds of window 1
    set item 3 of old_bounds to 2560
    set item 4 of old_bounds to 1440
    set bounds of window 1 to old_bounds
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks Ted. I based my solution on your code and negative coordinates.

Comment: I would stay away from moving and resizing using the application (Safari) window. I wrote a reusable handler to do resizing, accepting an app window as a parameter similar to the sample code, unfortunately, it behaves differently when acting on windows from different apps (Safari, Terminal, Console, etc). The sizing is also inconsistent, oftentimes I need to rerun the script just to get the correct window size.  I re-implemented my handler to use System Events, update position and size properties, and that worked for me without any issues.

Comment: @user3579815: you should write that up as a separate answer, or if you don't I may add it to mine.

Comment: I don't think I could give a more complete answer so I'm fine to give support via comments. Feel free to add it to your answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

suggestion to is to use this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set the bounds of window 1 to {260, 21, 1660, 1400}
    activate
end tell
```